# PHP, Google Drive Always Upload to My Own Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a Drive Upload System with PHP.

My codes are as follows, but with this code, I can receive verification and upload to the drive of the relevant person.

I want;

Using my own drive address as a storage medium and uploading all the data here.

```
    session_start();

if(!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {

        $url_array = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $url = $url_array[0];

        require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
        require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId('xxxx');
        $client->setClientSecret('yyyy');
        $client->setRedirectUri($url);
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
        $client->setAccessType("offline");
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('force'); 

        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            header('location:'.$url);exit;
        } elseif (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {
            $client->authenticate();
        }

        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);

        $checktoken = $client->isAccessTokenExpired($_SESSION['access_token']);

        if ($checktoken == true){
            
            $refresh_token=$_SESSION['refresh_token'];
            $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
            $checktoken==False;
            
        }

        $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $file = new Google_DriveFile();

            $a = array();
            $k = '-1';

            foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] as $file_name) {

                $k++;

                $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$k]);
                $file->setTitle($file_name);
                $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
                $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
                $parent = new Google_ParentReference();
                $parent->setId('1NyNNtNHKRqZJiwT7eTskvLzG7O9xR9oy');
                $file->setParents(array($parent));
                $a[] = $service->files->insert(
                    $file,
                    array(
                        'data' => file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$k]),
                        'mimeType' => $mime_type,
                    )
            );

        }

}
```

How can I do more? I really need help on this. Can you inform me? Or can you cite any source?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you have now?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have currently is going to upload the file to the account of the user who authorizes the code.  This is what oauth2 does.

If you want to upload to your persona drive account then you should be using a service account and not Oauth2.  Think of service account as a dummy user it has its own drive account.  But you can also share a folder on your person drive account with the  service account and then it will have permission to upload files to that account.

You will not need to go though any authorization that way.

```
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {   
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Just make sure to create service account credentials on Google developer console.